# Prove that $a^2 \equiv b^2 \pmod q$ if and only if $a\equiv\pm b \pmod q$ for any prime numbers $q$.

Tags: prime-numbers

Prove that $a^2 \equiv b^2 \pmod q$ if and only if $a\equiv\pm b \pmod q$ for any prime numbers $q$

homework question, please help.

Comment: Hint: $a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b)$

Answer (score 2):

If $q$ divides $a^2 - b^2 = (a-b)(a+b)$, then $q$ must divide either $a+b$ or $a-b$ because $q$ is prime. This gives $a = \pm b \hbox{ mod } q$.

Comment: I see, but what of the opposite direction?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

- The only if case is straightforward.
- The if case: Use the [Euclid's lemma.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma)